# Backbone.js with jQuery not altering the dom as expected

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

store-models.js model

```
    (function ($) {

  Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //Create a model to hold friend atribute
    name: null
  });

  Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    //This is our Friends collection and holds our Friend models
    initialize: function (models, options) {
      this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi);
      //Listen for new additions to the collection and call a view function if so
    }
  });

  CategoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("li"),
    initialize:function(){
          $(this.el).html(this.model.get("name"));
          console.log("initialize"+this.model.get("name"));
    },
    events:{
        "click": "showPrompt",
    },
    showPrompt : function(){
        alert("test");
    }
  });

  AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function () {
      this.friends = new Categories( null, { view: this });

      //Create a friends collection when the view is initialized.
      //Pass it a reference to this view to create a connection between the two
    },
    events: {
      "click #add-friend":  "showPrompt",
    },
    showPrompt: function () {
      var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
      var friend_model = new Category({ name: friend_name });
      //Add a new friend model to our friend collection
      this.friends.add( friend_model );
    },
    addFriendLi: function (mymodel) {
      //The parameter passed is a reference to the model that was added
      friendView = new CategoryView({model: mymodel});
      $("#categories").append(friendView.el);
      console.log(friendView.el);
      //Use .get to receive attributes of the model
    }
  });  

    setTimeout('addCategories()',2000);
//    var appview = new AppView;
})(jQuery);

function addCategories()
{
    var appview = new AppView;
    appview.showPrompt();

}
```

Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}This is the title{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/static/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/static/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <script src='/static/js/jquery.js' ></script>
    <script src='/static/js/underscore.js' ></script>
    <script src='/static/js/backbone.js' ></script>
    <script src="/static/js/tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/store-models.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="categories">
    </div>
</body>
```

The issue is that the code is not appending li elements to the categories-list , even though front he backbone.js code it looks like it should.

Any suggestions here??

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your Developer Tools Console? What is it you are seeing?

Comment: yes something on the lines  of the following

"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' in tabs.js @ 26"

Comment: I know the `on` method was introduced with jQuery 1.7 and it looks like you haven't specified a particular version to include. Are you sure your jQuery version is 1.7+? tabs.js most likely requires it.

Comment: yes this is something i need to checkout.. gimme a few minutes ill get back to you after updating the version if I was not using the latest one already

Comment: after updating the error seems to have gone away, but the actual issue still remains..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a beginning check this :

1. You've left your `addCategories()` function outside of the scope, and I think it would not access your AppView class
2. Remove the unnecessary quotes in setTimeout to supply a proper callback

   ```
   /* ... code ... */

   function addCategories()
   {
      var appview = new AppView;
      appview.showPrompt();
   } 

   setTimeout(addCategories,2000);

   })(jQuery);
   ```

Your code will work if you do the change

#### Edit:

You have no "li" element in your category view ( because you haven't created nothing )

That's why your CategoryView.el is always undefined.

Instead of setting it in the view extend, you should set it as soon as you have a model to fill it in.

```
CategoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize:function(){
      this.setElement($("<li>"+this.model.get("name")+"</li>"));
      log("initialize"+this.model.get("name"));
   },

   /* rest of code */
```

You could then experiment in the *updated* jsfiddle of your code which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drinchev/P4Z6J/2/)

Comment: I tried the changes and they dont seem to work.I don't think its an issue with the scope. Any other suggestions??

Comment: Did you mean this.el.setElement ?? coz this code throws en error "No method setElement for this"

Comment: And i was under the impression that if you do not specify el, or an unexistend el, then backbone creates a div internally for you

Comment: Yes but if you want to do this you'll have to set `tagName : "li"` not `el : $("li")` it's just a different approach, which I don't know you are looking for!

Comment: not this.el.setElement it's just this.setElement as in the example, you have to call the View method setElement... look at the sample code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10391/discussion-between-drinchev-and-neeraj)